# Total number of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let
$A$: set of all prime numbers smaller than 50
$B$: set of all natural numbers whose squares are less than 50,
then the total number of relation from set $A$ to set $B$, is

I got $n(A)=15$ , and $n(B)=7$ .

But could not understand how to find number of relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n(A) = 15$ and  $n(B)=7$
So no of elements in cartesion product of A and B$=15\times 7=105$.

So total no of relations possible $2^{105}$.

Comment: Why relation is $2^{105}$

Comment: Because all 15 element in the Cartesian product will have two choices whether to go to relation or not go to the relation.

Comment: @Koolman Try searching it on this site; it follows from the binomial theorem.

Comment: @sgrmshrsm7 then it should be $2^{15}$

Comment: @Koolman Sorry I did typo in the above comment it is actually 105 because 15*7=105